# Copy/Paste&Cut with Spacemacs on Terminal

Tags: key-bindings, copy-paste, motion

I'm new with emacs, and I'm a developer that uses IDE to develop, and I want to learn emacs.

I choose Spacemacs as customization because I think has a good keybinding for me, but now I miss a feature that is on the IDE, that IDE the possibility to paste copy and go back with the keyboard shortcut.

So, in conclusion, my question is:
What is a method to configure emacs (into terminal) to allow me to copy and paste from a view to another, and how I can change the keybinding with somethings more similar to `SPC C` to copy `SPC V` to paste and `SPC` go back?

Comment: It sounds like you can (and if so, please do) remove Spacemacs from the equation. It sounds like you have a question about copy+paste followed by moving "back" somewhere. But the question isn't clear, so far. Please elaborate - say what behavior you're looking for, step by step.

Comment: I'm asking the method to configure emacs (terminal) to allow me to copy and past from a view to another

Comment: If you think that additional info isn't in the question and it helps, then add it to the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own. Thx.

Comment: @Drew done, thanks :-)